# Autobahn-js failes to connect to Ratchet Server (Wamp)

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, autobahn

I've already checked plenty of questions and tutorials and I'm following the official documentation from socketme portal. I'm running this on XAMPP/Localhost.

Websocket works, when I'm not using the WAMP interface. Otherwise, it fails to connect and doesn't state any reason.

Error is: "app.js:6200 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket' failed: connection closed unreachable"

Server

```
$server = new \Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080);
$server->route('/socket', new WebSocketHandler, array('*'));
$server->run();
```

WebSocketHandler is a basic implementation of `WampServerInterface` and only includes the abstracted methods without any change.

On the client side, I'm doing the following to try a connection via autobahn-js:

```
           var connection = new Autobahn.Connection({

            transports: [{
                type: 'websocket',
                port: 8080,
                host: 'localhost',
                url: 'ws://localhost:8080/socket'
            }],
            realm: 'realm1'
        });

        connection.onopen = function(session) {
            app.content = app.content + `connected!`
        };

        connection.onclose = function(reason, details) {
            app.content = app.content + `onclose!`
        }

        connection.open();
```

I've done something wrong in this implementation, but I can't figure it out. I've tried avoiding the `->route` approach and using the following vanilla approach:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new WampServer(
              new WebSocketHandler()
              )
        )
    ),
    8080
);
```

But, it didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Latest Autobahn implements WAMP v2. I've tried using the Thruway router implementation, but i have zero control over the onMessage, onOpen, onClose, etc. methods, therefore, I want to stay using Ratchet WAMP v1. 

The bounty is for a compatiable library that could communication with the WAMP v1 backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Autobahn.js 0.8.2 to connect it to Ratchet (WAMP v1) and it's a pretty old implementation and also ab 0.8.2 is extremely old.

You should navigate your work to Thruway. I tried doing it, but I couldn't find any custom implementation of Thruway RatcherRouter (onMessage, onOpen, etc.), therefore, I decided to do my own (pretty bad) implementation of Ratchet.

TL;DR: Switch to Thruway.